# extract out matching rows from dataframe with special character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
>df
gene_ids    baseMean    log2FoldChange
LOC_Os03g58080  15.8597614967997    -20.7189803704191
LOC_Os06g17030  15.8597614967997    -20.7189803704191
LOC_Os11g01380  779.386943289599    -12.3657001542033

>df2
gene_id GO  
LOC_Os01g01010.1    GO:0030234
LOC_Os06g17030.1    GO:0007165
LOC_Os06g17030.2    GO:0006139
LOC_Os01g01010.1    GO:0009056
```

I would like to compare both the dataframes and if the strings in df.geneids column matches df2.gene_id column (before the '.' character), i would like to write out the matching rows from df2 into a new dataframe

expected output:

```
gene_id GO
LOC_Os06g17030.1    GO:0007165
LOC_Os06g17030.2    GO:0006139
```

Help will be much appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the part before the dot with a regex and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = df2[df2['gene_id'].str.extract(r'^([^.]+)', 
          expand=False).isin(df['gene_ids'])]
```

Output:

```
            gene_id          GO
1  LOC_Os06g17030.1  GO:0007165
2  LOC_Os06g17030.2  GO:0006139
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qlB4Tx/1)

*NB. You could also use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) in place of `extract`, but it's a bit less efficient.*

```
out = df2[df2['gene_id'].str.split('.', regex=False).str[0].isin(df['gene_ids'])]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway. Using extract got the job done perfectly. Appreciate it